# 'dialogDefinition' event is not called for any dialog while initialization of CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, dialog, ckeditor

I am using dialogDefinition event to change the definition of the image2 dialog of the Enhanced Image plugin.I am using this code -

```
CKEDITOR.appendTo("editor1" ,
      {
          on: {
              dialogDefinition: function (ev) {

                  console.log("Inside dialog definition");
                  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
                  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
                  if (dialogName == 'image2') {
                    console.log("Inside Upload");
                    dialogDefinition.removeContents('Upload');
                    dialogDefinition.addContents({
                    title: "Upload",
                    id: "upload",
                    label: "Upload",
                    elements: [{
                     type: "html",
                     html: "<form>{%csrf_token%}<input id='imageupload' type='file' name='files[]'/></form>"
                    }]
                 });
                }
                },
            },
```

However when I click on any dialog, this event is not called as the console message did not get printed and the definition of image2 dialog did not change.

Is there any way to find out why this event is not called or how to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that [`dialogDefinition`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-dialogDefinition) event belongs to [`CKEDITOR`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR), not [`CKEDITOR.editor`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor). The right way to listen on `dialogDefinition` is like:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    ...
});
```